# Jcrop selection area getting height

Tags: jquery, html, image-processing, crop, jcrop

I have used Jcrop v2.0.0 for cropping an image in a popup.

and the following is my Javascript code for the same.

```
var imageCropWidth = 0;
var imageCropHeight = 0;
var cropPointX = 0;
var cropPointY = 0;

$('#CropImage').attr('src', '/Users/3/images/Umbraco.jpg');
$(document).ready(function () {
        initCrop();
    });

    function initCrop() {
        $('#CropImage').Jcrop({
            onSelect: setCoordsAndImgSize,
            boxWidth: 260,
            //boxHeight: 260,
        });
    }

function setCoordsAndImgSize(e) {
imageCropWidth = e.w;
        imageCropHeight = e.h;

        cropPointX = e.x;
        cropPointY = e.y;
}
```

Now after using boxWidth I am struggling to get accurate x, y coordinates of selected crop area I think it's due to Jcrop adding height to Image or so.

[image]

What I have tried till now is :

-> Re-structure the HTML / removed parent element height (as suggested my many post)

-> have remove boxHeight : and only given box with

-> have try with x2, y2 manipulation

-> event try with jcrop truesize.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the issue was when loading the image dynamically over the, so jcrop was taking the size of the last image.

And same can be managed by setImage

> setImage(SelectedImage.attr('src'));

So the JS code will be.

```
var jcrop_api;

function initCrop() {
        var ratioW = ($('#CropImage')[0].naturalWidth);
        var ratioH = ($('#CropImage')[0].naturalHeight); 
        $('#CropImage').Jcrop({
            onSelect: setCoordsAndImgSize,
            boxWidth: 260,
            boxHeight: 260,
            setSelect: [0, 0, ratioW, ratioH]
        }, function () {
            jcrop_api = this;
        });
    }
```

// call on change of Image

```
jcrop_api.setImage(SelectedImage.attr('src'));
```